# How to add multiple Cloud Anchors using AR Core?

Tags: android, arcore

After completing the tutorial on ARCore Cloud Anchors, I was wondering if anyone managed to host and retrieve multiple Anchors in one Session and would like to share some ideas and/or code. Thank you!